# Generating two random prime numbers in JAVA

Tags: java, random

I'm trying to generate two random prime numbers in JAVA, however, I want the loop to keep repeating itself until both of those two variables are prime numbers, and then they output themselves.

The **p** and **q** variables are randomized by the **Math.random()** function and are in the range of 2 to 128 (excluding the 128).

Here is my code:

```
int pRandom = (int) (Math.random() * (127 - 2) + 2);
int qRandom = (int) (Math.random() * (127 - 2) + 2);
int p = pRandom;
int q = qRandom;

for (int i = 1; i < p; i++) {
boolean isPPrime = true;

for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
    if (i % j == 0) {
        isPPrime = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (isPPrime){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YAY!");
    break;
  }
    System.out.println("P value: " + p + "\n" + "Q value: " + q);
}
```

Comment: your inner for loop will never be executed. See the condition of the for loop.
"j < 1". It should be "j < i".

Comment: @SubrataDey, I'm still getting a prime output:

P Value: 68

Comment: That just makes the P Value a **1**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```
public class RandomPrimeGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while (true) {
            int pRandom = (int) (Math.random() * (127 - 2) + 2);
            if(isPrime(pRandom)){
                System.out.println("Got Random Prime P :"+pRandom);
                break;
            }
        }
        while(true){
            int qRandom = (int) (Math.random() * (127 - 2) + 2);
            if(isPrime(qRandom)){
                System.out.println("Got Random Prime Q :"+qRandom);
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    private static boolean isPrime(int n) {
       int i;
       for(i=2;i<=Math.sqrt(n);i++){
           if(n % i == 0){
               return false;
           }
       }
       return true;
    }

}
```